# How to search a word in emails using win32.com

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import win32com.client as client

outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
for message in inbox.Items:
    if 'Ebay' in message:
        if message.UnRead == True:
            if 'Ebay' in message:
                print('1')
                message.UnRead = False
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: This object does not support enumeration
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd probably need to do something like `'Ebay' in message.Content` (or whatever is the correct attribute on the message object – refer to the documentation for Outlook's objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **body** on message variable in loop. Update your code with following line.

```
if 'Ebay' in message.body:
```

Comment: My pleasure :) If it is worked, you could accept my answer :)

Comment: Do you mind telling me how I can convert the message.body's characters into small characters? message.body.lower()? I think it worked. What do I have to do in order to accept your answer?

Comment: yes exactly, you could do that with message.body.lower() and do not forgot to update your new variable with that. For accepting, on the left part of my answer, you will see gray tick. If you click that, you will accept my response as an answer :)

Comment: Did it thanks. But now, I run into another problem, could you please help? I post a new question. I am very close to my chatbot for buying/selling items and I need this for my resume.

Comment: I will examine when I am available

Comment: Do you have time now?